# Is there a formulae to calculate the number of dimensions or principal components that corresponds to a particular variance magnitude?

Tags: neural-network, pca, eigenvalue, eigenvector, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to implement PCA in pytorch, given a covariance matrix, its eigenvalues, eigenvectors and a proportion of variance to be captured from a data matrix, is there a formulae to calculate the number of dimensions or principal components that corresponds to the variance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. The percentage of variance explained by the first N principal components is the sum of the first N eigenvalues divided by the sum of all eigenvalues!

Basically it's the magnitude of the eigenvalue that tells you the importance of the feature.